# How can i create a user with AuthMethod as ldap using p4api or something else in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, perforce, p4api.net

Can't find AuthMethod flag/member in User class or am i missing something ?

user class members
http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/doc/manuals/p4api.net/p4api.net_reference/html/AllMembers_T_Perforce_P4_User.htm

Thanks in advance !!